# PlanarMechanics library in OpenModelica 1.16.2

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

How to fix the translation error for the built-in examples of the PlanarMechanics library in OpenModelica 1.16.2:

```
[1] 22:11:50 Scripting Warning
Requested package Modelica of version 4.0.0, but this package was already loaded with version 3.2.3. There are no conversion annotations for this version but 4.0.0 is newer than 3.2.3. There is a possibility that 3.2.3 remains backwards compatible, but it is not loaded so OpenModelica cannot verify this.

[2] 22:11:50 Translation Error
[PlanarMechanics.Interfaces.Frame: 3:3-3:29]: Class SI.Position not found in scope PlanarMechanics.Interfaces.Frame.

[3] 22:11:50 Translation Error
Error occurred while flattening model PlanarMechanics.Examples.Pendulum
```

Comment: I would suggest installing 1.17.0 or the nightly-build which has Modelica 4.0.0. If you want to stick with 1.16, download MSL 4.0.0 from https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica-ModelicaStandardLibrary/archive/58d77b59ed75d8c2f60e436b4169e8e1f1bcfee6.zip
and unpack it in OpenModelica/lib/omlibrary/

Comment: I unpacked the archive https://github.com/dzimmer/PlanarMechanics/archive/refs/tags/v1.4.1.zip into OpenModelica1.16.2-64bit\lib\omlibrary\ and use the file package.mo to load the library into OMEdit.